# Why when adding the audio analyser the sounds stops playing ? Webaudio Api

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Im following this [tut](http://fourthof5.com/audio-visualisation-with-the-web-audio-api) about using the data of a sound to move stuff.

Until now it works correctly, it plays a sound,this is the code:

```
/* Hoist some variables. */
var audio,
    context = new (window.AudioContext ||
                   window.webAudioContext ||
                   window.webkitAudioContext)(),
    /* Create a script processor node with a `bufferSize` of 1024. */
    processor = context.createScriptProcessor(1024),
    /* Create an analyser node */
    analyser = context.createAnalyser();

/* Wire the processor into our audio context. */
processor.connect(context.destination);
/* Wire the analyser into the processor */
analyser.connect(processor);

/* Define a Uint8Array to receive the analysers data. */
var data = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);

/* Try instantiating a new AudioContext, throw an error if it fails. */
try {
    /* Setup an AudioContext. */
    context = new AudioContext();
} catch(e) {
    throw new Error('The Web Audio API is unavailable');
}

/* Define a `Sound` Class */
var Sound = {
    /* Give the sound an element property initially undefined. */
    element: undefined,
    /* Define a class method of play which instantiates a new Media Element
     * Source each time the file plays, once the file has completed disconnect 
     * and destroy the media element source. */
    play: function() { 
        var sound = context.createMediaElementSource(this.element);
        this.element.onended = function() {
            sound.disconnect();
            sound = null;
        }
        sound.connect(context.destination);

        /* Call `play` on the MediaElement. */
        this.element.play();
    }
};

/* Create an async function which returns a promise of a playable audio element. */
function loadAudioElement(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var audio = new Audio();
        audio.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
            /* Resolve the promise, passing through the element. */
            resolve(audio);
        });
        /* Reject the promise on an error. */
        audio.addEventListener('error', reject);
        audio.src = url;
    });
}

/* Let's load our file. */
loadAudioElement('/audio/shorter.mp3').then(function(elem) {
    /* Instantiate the Sound class into our hoisted variable. */
    audio = Object.create(Sound);
    /* Set the element of `audio` to our MediaElement. */
    audio.element = elem;
    /* Immediately play the file. */
    audio.play();
}, function(elem) {
    /* Let's throw an the error from the MediaElement if it fails. */
    throw elem.error;
});
```

but i want to use the audio analyser data to move things...

So i have to modify the sound class, to instead of wiring the audio's media element source only into the audio context, it now should wire through the analyser as well.

But when I add this code, the sound stops playing...

```
 /* Removed for brevity... */
    play: function() { 
        var sound = context.createMediaElementSource(this.element);
        this.element.onended = function() {
            sound.disconnect();
            sound = null;
            /* Noop the audioprocess handler when the file finishes. */
            processor.onaudioprocess = function() {};
        }
        /* Add the following line to wire into the analyser. */
        sound.connect(analyser);
        sound.connect(context.destination);

        processor.onaudioprocess = function() {
            /* Populate the data array with the frequency data. */
            analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(data);
        };
        /* Call `play` on the MediaElement. */
        this.element.play();
    }
```

This is the full code that stops working:

```
/* Hoist some variables. */
var audio,
    context = new (window.AudioContext ||
                   window.webAudioContext ||
                   window.webkitAudioContext)(),
    /* Create a script processor node with a `bufferSize` of 1024. */
    processor = context.createScriptProcessor(1024),
    /* Create an analyser node */
    analyser = context.createAnalyser();

/* Wire the processor into our audio context. */
processor.connect(context.destination);
/* Wire the analyser into the processor */
analyser.connect(processor);

/* Define a Uint8Array to receive the analysers data. */
var data = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);

/* Try instantiating a new AudioContext, throw an error if it fails. */
try {
    /* Setup an AudioContext. */
    context = new AudioContext();
} catch(e) {
    throw new Error('The Web Audio API is unavailable');
}

/* Define a `Sound` Class */
var Sound = {
    /* Give the sound an element property initially undefined. */
    element: undefined,
    /* Define a class method of play which instantiates a new Media Element
     * Source each time the file plays, once the file has completed disconnect 
     * and destroy the media element source. */
    /* Removed for brevity... */
play: function() { 
    var sound = context.createMediaElementSource(this.element);
    this.element.onended = function() {
        sound.disconnect();
        sound = null;
        /* Noop the audioprocess handler when the file finishes. */
        processor.onaudioprocess = function() {};
    }
    /* Add the following line to wire into the analyser. */
    sound.connect(analyser);
    sound.connect(context.destination);

    processor.onaudioprocess = function() {
        /* Populate the data array with the frequency data. */
        analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(data);
    };
    /* Call `play` on the MediaElement. */
    this.element.play();
}

};

/* Create an async function which returns a promise of a playable audio element. */
function loadAudioElement(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var audio = new Audio();
        audio.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
            /* Resolve the promise, passing through the element. */
            resolve(audio);
        });
        /* Reject the promise on an error. */
        audio.addEventListener('error', reject);
        audio.src = url;
    });
}

/* Let's load our file. */
loadAudioElement('/audio/shorter.mp3').then(function(elem) {
    /* Instantiate the Sound class into our hoisted variable. */
    audio = Object.create(Sound);
    /* Set the element of `audio` to our MediaElement. */
    audio.element = elem;
    /* Immediately play the file. */
    audio.play();
}, function(elem) {
    /* Let's throw an the error from the MediaElement if it fails. */
    throw elem.error;
});
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you trying to load audio from a different domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should connect the analyser to the destination to make it work.

`sound.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(context.destination);`